# System Navigation bar getting background color instead of being transparent

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The system navigation bar on android won't be transparent when executing this in flutter:

```
// tell app to use fullscreen mode with rendering system ui like status bar
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);

// set color of system navigation bar to transparent
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));
```

In my case the `NavigationBar` should be visible under the system navigation bar, but instead the background color is shown. Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

[image]
The system navigation bar should have the same color as the `NavigationBar` above, but as shown in the picture it just shows a white color.

Comment: add pictures, 1. what u want to 2. what u r getting

Comment: Since currently the edit function does not work, take a look here: https://upcdn.io/W142hJk/image/demo/4mdUasB36P.png?w=600&h=600&fit=max&q=70
The white part at the bottom should have the same color as the blue part above. Since the colors are used dynamically I can't just set the color specifically. That's why I want to set it to transparent to always fit the `NavigationBar`.

Comment: then don't use Colors. transparent but blue color instead like Color()... [~remember u won't be able to declare predefined color value as parameter like Colors.red, Colors.whire etc but this Color(0xFF.......)]

Comment: Didn't work either. I think it also would be surprising if because Colors.transparent does nothing then returning a black color with alpha layer being fully transparent (`Color(0x00000000)` is getting returned).

Answer (score 0):

Its working, look

```dart
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Color(0xFF202935),
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarColor: Color(0xFF202935),
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

[img result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1coPUJOkpUsCOpxxGTaAOecTbYXH7TZxv/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: As mentioned in the question this sets the color to a specific value. Since I'm using dynamic colors introduced in Material Design 3 of Android the `NavigationBar` uses a color defined by the wallpaper. I also want the system navigation bar to fit the color the `NavigationBar` uses so I set the color to transparent (which by the way worked in the past). But then it won't get transparent but white instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's late to answer this but others will benefit from this. To achieve the following results: [image]

You need to

- Wrap your Scaffold widget with an **AnnotatedRegion** widget
- Use the native **ElevationOverlay** class to set the colors you want for the system navigation bar

---

Here is exactly how

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color navColor = ElevationOverlay.applySurfaceTint(
        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceTint,
        3);
    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarContrastEnforced: true,
        systemNavigationBarColor: navColor,
        systemNavigationBarDividerColor: navColor,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness:
            Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                ? Brightness.dark
                : Brightness.light,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(...))}
```

**If the content of the page goes below the Navigation bar**, just wrap your Scaffold's body with a Padding widget, and set the padding to the height of the navigation bar (50 not exactly sure about it)